# Python function to find the highest frequency number

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I'm working on a Python function that is supposed to return the number with the highest frequency in an array. In cases where two numbers or more  have the same frequency, it should return the larger number.

However, I'm facing an issue with my current implementation.

```py
def highest_rank(arr):
    count_num = {}
    for i in arr:
        if i not in count_num:
            count_num[i] = 0
        else:
            count_num[i] = arr.count(i)
    return max(count_num, key=count_num.get)
```

In the this example `[9, 48, 1, 8, 44, 45, 32]` , I expect the function to return `48` but it return 9

Comment: Try `print(count_num)` before returning, and you'll see what is going wrong.

Comment: arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True) first, should help

Comment: @HildermesJoséMedeirosFilho but that makes the whole process O(N log N), when it can be done in O(N) time.

Comment: It would, but neither time nort speed was a requirment, loop in python...thansk but no. It should be something consider in design.

Comment: @slothrop the current solution is O(N^2) so sorting wouldn't slow it down by much. First N is the obvious loop and for each iteration in that loop, `.count()` is called which again loops over the entire dataset, making it O(N^2)

Comment: @OM222O quite so, when I said "*can* be done in O(N) time" I should have clarified that that also involves replacing `count_num[i] = arr.count(i)` with `count_num[i] = count_num[i] + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over unique (and ordered) items of the list to avoid case study.

Maximality condition first for the frequency and then for the item.

```
def highest_rank(arr):
    count_num = dict.fromkeys(arr, 0)
    for i in count_num:
        count_num[i] = arr.count(i)
    return max(count_num.items(), key=lambda p: (p[1], p[0]))[0]


l = [9, 48, 1, 8, 44, 45, 32]
print(highest_rank(l))
#48

l = [9, 48, 1, 8, 44, 8, 8, 45, 32]
print(highest_rank(l))
#8
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a very fast solution that finds the correct result (as tested with a few different inputs)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def highest_rank(arr):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    highest_rank = 0
    for num in arr:
        cnt = count[num]+1
        count[num]=cnt
        highest_rank_cnt = count[highest_rank]
        if cnt > highest_rank_cnt or (cnt == highest_rank_cnt and num > highest_rank):
            highest_rank = num
    return highest_rank
            
print(highest_rank([9, 48, 1, 8, 44, 45, 32])) # Prints 48 as expected
```

A quick comparison between my method and your solution (applied the fix from accepted solution):

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

def highest_rank(arr):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    highest_rank = 0
    highest_rank_cnt = 0
    for num in arr:
        cnt = count[num]+1
        count[num]=cnt
        if cnt > highest_rank_cnt or (cnt == highest_rank_cnt and num > highest_rank):
            highest_rank = num
            highest_rank_cnt = cnt
    return highest_rank
            
def highest_rank_slow(arr):
    count_num = {}
    for i in arr:
        if i not in count_num:
            count_num[i] = 0
        else:
            count_num[i] = arr.count(i)
    return max(count_num,key=lambda x:(count_num.get(x),x))

nums = list(np.random.randint(0,1000,10_000))
%timeit highest_rank(nums)          # 2.97 ms ± 393 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit highest_rank_slow(nums)     # 1.56 s ± 52.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In fact, my approach can do this for a million numbers in roughy 230ms which is still faster than your solution for 10K numbers since `.count()` is REPEATEDLY looping through the list instead of counting in one go.

Edit:

If you don't want to use the built-in `defaultdict`, you can simply use your `if num not in count` trick:

```
def highest_rank_no_defaultdict(arr):
    count = {}
    highest_rank = 0
    highest_rank_cnt = 0
    for num in arr:
        if num not in count:
            cnt=1
        else:
            cnt = count[num]+1
        count[num]=cnt
        if cnt > highest_rank_cnt or (cnt == highest_rank_cnt and num > highest_rank):
            highest_rank = num
            highest_rank_cnt = cnt
    return highest_rank
```

this is both more verbose and a bit slower than using `defaultdict` so unless you absolutely need to, stick with `defaultdict`.

Comment: Thank you Is there a way without using external libraries?

Comment: @XMehdi01 `collections` is an internal library that comes with Python, so it's not external, but I have updated the answer to show you how to do it without `defaultdict`.

Comment: Better don't use NumPy, or at the very least use `tolist()` to get a list of Python ints instead of your list of NumPy ints.

Answer (score 3):

Make your life easy.

```
from statistics import multimode

def highest_rank(arr):
    return max(multimode(arr))
```

Benchmark with the accepted answer's solution on `nums = random.choices(range(1000), k=10000)` ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVTNjtMwEL5wylOYU20IVVt-hCqFGye02geooshNxluzsR3ZDmpV7ZNw2QvckXgCHoOnYeykqbtbekntme_zN994_P1nd_A7ox8ff_RevPn498VvYY0itWlbqL002hGpOmM9aUDwvvWNrH0Wc7xUIP0pPKyGiPPcS-dlPYEVIqUyDeREAdc5pjTwLRujluvGqNPKHVyW4WlkJ-924HyF4fvqC7TtgXJr2Toj-LPge6uJ4ns6kccwuwK-vVmtVrcJuja99qRIi6JSexaDKRRzFnFTGEt0r4jUBGkGlsgUeSLfBuPl6-U5NG0WmDVtXyhL4WmgnNKliGd8eo5DRTTii-cxdDTKvYSxs-4rhWJ-am0azTLRa2xncaUp-TWvswzZQv7Q23m9M7IGR3F5B3S5WCxYTu6L8GeBHcMil4M22Hd48YIaowE_ZvsV15RNTRChBVHNuRgLDruI2YKGY1lq3kgoXWS8NGA6bCCYYtAicCR9WYxpl1DLpQPyeV9DF8aEzm6kU9zXuxmWExLCQAQDjmJNNuUT6Q8xJdzTMCuOiqQzPqA2nrwiS3gbcT7gHM4GNDTSbkTJNuv3ZZk4EHsmZscwX9Q7tv4wX4kH8ucXOcZhi3vv4h42Zjb5WQXyqS2Jjv-ZHTWixGHiacvVtuHrk_V5uEZbsMWSXSJG3XPedaCxjicdHcuLZ-HNgEMRnUn0dBYnlJ78yomYV5XmCqqKDY_X-Iad3rJ_)):

```
  0.80 ± 0.01 ms  highest_rank_Kelly
  1.89 ± 0.04 ms  highest_rank_OM222O
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all numbers in the example are distinct they will all get a count of 0 due to the first if statement checking their existence in the `count_num` dictionary.

also avoid using `count(x)` as it is highly inefficient in this context and will probably fail test cases that test running time of the proposed algorithm. Insteard, try counting each number and increase its count in the dictionary as you did. if the number is not in the dictionary then its count should be 1 as you just encountered it for the first time.

regarding `max()` usage.. it will give you the key which has the highest value but if two keys have the same value `max()` doesn't guarantee to give you the highest key so think on how you can find it yourself in a linear time (hint: keep the highest count found).

Answer (score 0):

Max returns the first result in the dictionary.

Using your function definition, this outputs 5 as expected:

```
x= [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
highest_rank(sorted(x, reverse=True))
```

Your function definition also includes some redundancy.

```
def highest_rank(arr):
    count_num = {}
    for i in arr:
        count_num[i] = arr.count(i)
    return max(count_num, key=count_num.get)
```

Will be functionally similar.

Comment: *"Will be functionally similar."* In fact, it removes a bug present in OP's implementation. However, remember the additional requirement: *"In cases where two numbers or more have the same frequency, it should return the larger number."*

Comment: Data preprocessing should handle -- `sorted(x, reverse=True)`. In rare cases, the dictionary may not store in order.

Comment: You're right, if you sort the array first then the output will be correct.

Comment: It's definitely helpful to remember the highest abstraction is a reverse sort on key= (frequency, value), and making that explicit could help future readers of the code. (Or as an ugly one-liner, `f= lambda x: sorted([(x.count(v), v) for v in x], reverse=True)[0]`).

Comment: Kind of, yes. But actually, we don't need to fully sort the sequence of `(frequency, value)` 2-tuples. We just need to get its maximal element, which can be done in O(N), compared to the O(N log N) required for a full sort. So solutions which don't require sorting exist (e.g. OM222O's answer), and those will likely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

`max()` by default returns the first key stored in case of <strike>race conditions</strike> tie, your key in particular is just there to help you identify the key with the largest value, and nothing more

Since you want to do two things, you can modify your key to return both the value stored in dictionary and the key; so that in cases where the values are same, you can compare the exact key.

Do this instead:

`max(count_num,key=lambda x:(count_num.get(x),x))`

This gives it two arguments to compare against first the value and then the key

Comment: *" in case of race conditions"* I know what you're trying to say, but "tie" is a better term than "race condition" here. "Race condition" describes a dependency on the time ordering of concurrent processes.

Comment: @XMehdi01 This solves your immediate problem but it's a highly inefficient solution as you loop through the dataset multiple times. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @OM222O Your answer is good, but I don't want to call external libraries

Comment: @XMehdi01, you can just use the regular dictionary instead of the default dict, besides "collections" comes pre-installed with Python; so not something you'd have to install

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Counter class from collections.  It provides a `most_common` function to identify the highest count.  Once you know the highest frequency, you can pick the highest number with that count.

```
A = [9, 48, 1, 8, 44, 45, 32]

from collections import Counter

counts    = Counter(A)
(_,freq), = counts.most_common(1)
N         = max(n for n,c in counts.items() if c==freq)

print(N)  # 48
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def find_highest_frequency_number(data):
    # Create a dictionary to store the frequencies of each number
    frequencies = {}
    for num in data:
        if num not in frequencies:
            frequencies[num] = 0
        frequencies[num] += 1

    # Find the number with the highest frequency
    highest_frequency = 0
    highest_frequency_number = None
    for num, frequency in frequencies.items():
        if frequency > highest_frequency:
            highest_frequency = frequency
            highest_frequency_number = num

    return highest_frequency_number
```

Comment: *"In cases where two numbers or more have the same frequency, it should return the larger number."*